# Swift - Array Filter not removing objects

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, filter, swift3

I have an Array of Strings as shown:

[image]

I also have an array of objects that contain:

[image]

When I run the following line:

```
let filterNo = self.responseObjs.filter({!formItemIds.contains(String(describing: $0.formItemId))})
```

I expect `filterNo` to be empty as all the `formItemId`s are contained in the array. It is however not removing any of the items. Am I missing something basic?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `describing` from the `init` of `String` and use [`Nil-Coalescing Operator`](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH6-ID72) with `$0.formItemId` to unwrapped optional.

```
let filterNo = self.responseObjs.filter({!formItemIds.contains(String($0.formItemId ?? 0))})
```

You are not getting filtered data because your `formItemId` property is optional and using `String(describing: $0.formItemId)` give you output like `Optional(98)`

Comment: @Alan Welcome mate :)